# Scanning input into char array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, java.util.scanner

I was trying to store input as

```
5 
3DRP 3QEW
8AQW 9ADA
```

I want to read that input in as a copy paste and put it. I've tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userNumber;
    userNumber = scan.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = userNumber.split("[ ]");
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

My goal is to basically read that input in as a copy paste into the IDE or through a file a .txt and then store every single character besides whitespaces into a char array that is 1d or 2d.

Comment: and what problem are you facing? apart from `split("[ ]");` doesn't seem to be required for your input.

Comment: Apart from that: Don't use scanner.close(), as it will close the System.in stream.

Comment: @nullpointer I want to read the entire line of code but it only reads the first line when I copy paste it. I want to only read the actual ASCII not the white spaces, in that case the white spaces are included

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to read 3 lines from the console, remove all the white spaces from that text and store it as a `char` array.

If that is the case, here is how you could do that:

```
    int numberOfLinesToRead = 3;
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        while(numberOfLinesToRead-- > 0){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String noSpaces = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            buff.append(noSpaces);
        }
        char[] characters = buff.toString().toCharArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(characters));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: any specific reason to use the `try with resources` other than to close the stream automatically ? Seems a bit overkill to me, since Scanner doesn't throw any checked exceptions

Comment: @ChandlerBing Just a habit, comes in handy when changing the stream. There are no modifications required if I change `System.in` to a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: @Titus what if I don't know the number of lines I want to read?

Comment: @Peerless You'll have to find a way of stopping and set that as the condition of the loop. For example, you can stop reading lines when you enter something like `stop` into the console. If you what to do that, you can change the loop's condition to this `while(!line.equals("stop"))` and define the `line` variable outside of the loop

Comment: @Titus You shouldn't close the scanner, as it will also close System.in, which shouldn't be closed at all.